# Projectile Y-axis start position - 2.5D Platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this issue and I can't fix it. I've already tried to search on internet but I found nothing.
The "projectile spawn" is situated next to my character. When I left-click on my mouse, the projectile starts shooting going forward (in the Z-axis at 20 speed, for example) but there is this issue that is making me mad. Sometimes it starts from the right place, sometimes under and under every click.

```
public Rigidbody projectile;
public float speed = 20;

private Transform spawnPoint;
private int SPAWN_DISTANCE = 1;

void Awake()
{
    spawnPoint = transform.Find("SpawnPoint");
}

void Update ()
{   
    //
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            atkSpeed = 0.2f;
            Shoot(projectile);
            attackTime = atkSpeed;
            chargeLevel = 0;
        }
    //

}

void Shoot(Rigidbody proj){
        Rigidbody _projBody = Instantiate(proj, spawnPoint.position + SPAWN_DISTANCE * transform.forward, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
        _projBody.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0,speed));
}
```

Video of what is happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLgrfl2zU9w

EDIT: I SOLVED MYSELF YESTERDAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an Empty GameObject where you want the projectile to spawn from. Nest it inside the character that fires.

Then find the `SpawnPoint`.

```
private Transform spawnPoint;
private int SPAWN_DISTANCE = 1;

void Awake()
{
    spawnPoint = transform.Find("SpawnPoint");
}
```

Also make this change to your shooting.

```
void Shoot()
{
    Rigidbody _projBody = Instantiate(projectile, spawnPoint.position + SPAWN_DISTANCE * transform.forward, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
    _projBody.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0,speed));
}
```

Comment: When I read the code I thought "It'll work!" but it's not working :/ . Still the same problem of the video. Thank you for your time anyway :)